# What are the new Rails critical security fixes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection

I got these updates from rails:

> I'd like to announce that 3.2.11, 3.1.10, 3.0.19, and 2.3.15 have been released. These releases contain two extremely critical security fixes so please update IMMEDIATELY.
>   [link](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/)

as it says it's critical. I just updated my application with rails 3.1 to 3.11 and did `bundle update rails`. My questions are:

1. What was the actual loophole in rails that has now been fixed?
   As a learner I'm eager to understand what the problem was and how has it been fixed. I couldn't get anywhere about this.
2. Is it really a big loophole, and is there any problem for all Rails application which haven't been updated?

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://www.insinuator.net/2013/01/rails-yaml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an explanation of the hack : http://charlie.bz/blog/rails-3.2.10-remote-code-execution

And the original post by tenderlove : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ

Basically, anyone can inject XML and instantiate any kind of Ruby object using YAML ... it's complicated, but works on all apps (except the patched one of course, and Rails 1.X) and can even execute system commands ...

Anyone having Rails apps around should already have upgraded ... if not, do it NOW!